# How to send BatchRequest?

Tags: php, json, api, google-analytics

It's been first time when I am going to use an APi for working with a Web Application. Google Analytics Dev-Guides show a Basic sample which is shown below.

I am TOTALLY UNAWARE of how to execute it..Okay, I would replace ViewId with mine.. Do I have to save it in .php Format ? or what ? anybody here can tell me step by step procedure

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
  "reportRequests":
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dateRanges": [{"startDate": "2014-11-01", "endDate": "2014-11-30"}],
      "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go though the steps in the [Hello Analytics API for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js)

- create a google developer project
- get your API credentials and a View ID you own.
- load the webpage.

If you get stuck on a particular step come back and ask for help.